# Show available rooms between to dates? SQL

Tags: java, sql, querying

I hope somebody can give me some little help here...

I'm programming a little booking program for a hotel, where I should be able to see a list of available rooms between two given dates. I'm experiencing an issue as in that if i search with an arrival date that is after the arrival date of the booking, the room will still show up as available...

My call to the database looks like this:

```
String SQLString = "select roomnumber, roomtypeid from rooms "
        + "where roomnumber not in "
        + "(select roomnumber from booking "
        + "where arrival between to_date(?, 'yyyy-mm-dd') "
        + "and to_date(?, 'yyyy-mm-dd')) and roomtypeid = ? order by roomnumber";
```

I have tried some different combinations of sql strings, but nothing helps. Can anybody give me a good hint?

```
CREATE TABLE BOOKING(
ARRIVAL             DATE ,
DEPARTURE           DATE,
RESERVATIONSNUMBER  INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
ROOMNUMBER          INTEGER,
PAID                INTEGER,
CUSTOMERID INTEGER,
NUMBEROFGUESTS INTEGER,
CONSTRAINT BOFK FOREIGN KEY(ROOMNUMBER) REFERENCES ROOMS(ROOMNUMBER),
CONSTRAINT CUIDFK FOREIGN KEY(CUSTOMERID) REFERENCES CUSTOMER(CUSTOMERID));
```

Comment: Could you provide a bit more information about your database? How is the booking table defined?

Comment: can you add plain SQL ?

Comment: I will add the sql for the booking table.

Comment: Make sure you're passing the right dates in your Java code. Once that is verified, check the results of the subquery - does it have the rooms you need excluded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how to look for overlapping bookings. You may want to change <= and >= to < and >, if same day is not considered a problem.

```
select roomnumber, roomtypeid
from rooms 
where roomnumber not in 
(
  select roomnumber 
  from booking 
  where departure >= to_date(? /* desired arrival date */, 'yyyy-mm-dd')
  and arrival <= to_date(? /* desired departure date */, 'yyyy-mm-dd')
)
and roomtypeid = ? /* desired room type */
order by roomnumber;
```

Comment: You are giving the list of occupied rooms, when OP asked for free ones (ok, it's just a matter or logical negation ...). But you **do** solve the ovelapping problem

Answer (score 0):

I think the only issue would be date format convert all the date fields to date and check the same.

Answer (score 0):

It will look something like this -

```
SELECT *
FROM rooms r
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM booking b
                  WHERE (?arrival_date_parameter BETWEEN arrival AND departure
                     OR arrival BETWEEN ?arrival_date_parameter AND ?departure_date_parameter)
                    AND r.roomnumber = b.roomnumber)
  AND roomtypeid = ?
ORDER BY roomnumber
```

Comment: I will try this. But what is r.roomnumber and b.roomnumber?